# HTTPS error on react project returning ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, msal.js

Sorry for the question but I am stumped,
Recently since reinstalling my node folder I have been getting the error when accessing my website with https

```
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

It also comes with an error in the developer console, but I don't know if its related or I'm just thinking too much into the error, it states

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
```

I was really wanting to use HTTPS as I'm currently using MSAL for authentication

I have tried a list of things such as:

- Reinstalling Node Folder
- Trying to remove core.js
- removing cookies from browser
- updating the sites certificate

At this point I'm all out of ideas.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: check the protocol in launch.json file?

Comment: Hi @Brent, thank you for responding, the problem is that I'm using npm start so there is no launch.json file sadly, Thank you anyways

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my package.json file, i didnt configure my certificate and key correctly.